# How to access a storage account from a datafactory in diff susbcriptions

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I have a azure data factory which has access via public endpoints. And I want to access a storage account which is in diff subscription which has public network enabled from selected virtual networks and ip addresses.

Now, I want to understand more from both the networking point of view and as per the diff options provided by azure to make such connections in between resources. What are the different ways available and which is the most recommended one.

I tried to connect using few options (mentioned below) but still could not establish connection. I must be making some mistakes due to the lack of my knowledge in networking.

1. I added the data factory instance in the storage account networking config under "Resource instances" which seems to be allowing access to certain resources. but it failed.
2. I tried to add the private endpoint at both resources end. I am still not sure in which subscription exactly I need to add this endpoint.

I get below error while trying to access the storage account from the data factory.
[image]

Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below procedure to create blob storage linked service by using private endpoint:

1. Create an integration runtime with virtual network configuration as shown below:

[image]

2. Go to the Azure Data Factory manage tab and create a new private endpoint by clicking the "New" option. Select the Azure SQL database option and choose your server name from the list. Click on "Create." This action will require approval from the SQL server.
3. In the blob storage account, go to the networking tab and select "Private endpoint connections." You will see a hyperlink that leads you to approve the private endpoint at the storage account level. Click on the hyperlink and approve it, as shown below:

[image]

4. After approving successfully, create a new blob storage linked service using the previously created integration runtime with the required details. The linked service will be tested successfully, as shown below:

[image]